# Umbraco back office menu doesn't show up

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to install Umbraco 7.5.3 on an empty project but the back office has no items in the menus. It doesn't also load anything in the content tree.

[image]
I tried to do a clean installation based on [this article](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/setup/install/install-umbraco-with-nuget) but it was the same.
I went with a clean web application, I even select .net 4.5.1 in a try, and in the wizard part, I went with custom installation and in DB part I've entered the SA account.

Comment: If you open the site in Chrome and fire up the inspector, do you see any javascript errors? It's possible something is going wrong loading the UI.

Comment: What @Tim said - this could give you an indication what is wrong. I suspect that perhaps some settings in IIS are not "correct" so that could be blocking the menu items from showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made it work. It sounds a bit strange, but it worked! I don't know why it wasn't on the how to page. and I still don't know what could be wrong :|

I had to set up the site on IIS and then accessing it using the domain address that I created.

So if anyone has the same problem do this:

1- create a new website set the directory to your websites address

> (yourdomain.com==> c:...\yourUmbraco project)

2- go to hosts file and add your domain

> (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)

add

> 127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com

3- give access to your app pool worker (or everyone in your risk :D )

4- access your backoffice using yourdomain.com/umbraco